# How to use LINQ to filter property of child collection using (.Any())

Tags: linq, nhibernate

How do I do the following SQL in LINQ? I am actually using LINQ to NHibernate (but maybe it's not possible in NHibernate LINQ due to embedded lambda expression I think). But I want to know generally how to do it in LINQ. I’ve never came across this situation before.

```
SELECT c.CustomerID, c.CustomerName --etc
FROM   Customers c
       INNER JOIN Orders o
         ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
WHERE  o.Status = 1

public class Customer
{
  public int CustomerID { get; set; }
  public string CustomerName { get; set; }  
  public IList<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
  public int OrderID { get; set; }
  public int CustomerID { get; set; }
}
```

I want to do something similar to this:

```
var customers = 
    (from c in Customers
    where c.Orders.Where(o => o.Status == 1)
    select c).ToList();
```

THANK YOU!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

the where statement returns a collection. you want to use the Any() method

```
var customers = from c in Customers
                where c.Orders.Any(o => o.Status = 1)
                select c
```

Comment: just tested, using Any() is better than double select as it return less and correct results, the generated sql looks like this:
SELECT COLUMNS
FROM Customers c
WHERE EXISTS(
   SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
   FROM Orders o
   WHERE (o.Status == 1)
   AND  c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
    )

Answer (score 0):

This solution requires that there is a relationship within LINQ between orders and customer(i.e Customer has an Orders Property) but you can use:

```
  var customers = 
        (From c in Customers, o In c.Orders
        Where o.Status == 1 
        Select c).ToList()
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for LAMBDA or straight LINQ to SQL? Are you just looking to do a join?

Here would be a join using a lambda:

```
var lambda =
Customers.Join (
    Orders,
    c => c.CustomerID,
    o => o.CustomerID,
    (c, o) => new { c, o }
)
.Where  (w => w.o.Status == 1)
.Select (s => s.c.CustomerID, s.c.CustomerName);
```